# <v-text-field type="datetime-local"> How to display minutes with 15mins interval

Tags: javascript, vue.js, datetimepicker, intervals, datetime-local

In this case, I would like to change the time interval to every 15min, like 1:00,1:15,1:30,1:45 in the right hand side selection part. which will display 00,15,30,45 only instead of 30,31,32 like shown in the photo.

The step="900" attribute does not work since it only controls when pressing up and down arrow while selecting the text.

Comment: *like shown in the photo* - The photo seems to be missing from your question. Regarding the actual issue - stepping is not working in Firefox 110, but it is in Chrome  110.0.5481.178 (both tested on a Windows 10 PC). I'm unable to test it in Safari or on mobile devices. What's your browser?

Comment: I am using chrome, it does work but only via keyboard, I want to modify the dropdown selection to 15min intervals which can be modified using a mouse.

Comment: If you want to influence the display on the time side of the native `input.showPicker()`, and have it show (in the date and time pop-up) 00 / 15 / 30 / 45 for minutes, that's not possible. You could file a feature request for this, or report it as a [problem with implementation](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/show-picker/#problem-with-the-implementation).